# How to manipulate string and remove the '\' from list box binding in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, listbox

I am getting value in My listbox as the below

```
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\Iteration\AS-Automation,
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\Iteration\Pluse Pheonix,
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\Iteration\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 1,
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\Iteration\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 10
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\AS-Automation,
MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix,
MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 1,
MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 10
```

My code

```
string selectedITeration = string.Empty;

foreach (ListItem lis in ListIteration.Items)
{
    if (lis.Selected == true)
    {
        selectedITeration += lis.Text + ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) the `\`:

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '\\'};
selectedITeration += (lis.Text.Trim(charsToTrim) + ",").Replace(@"\",@"\\");
```

Comment: what to do abt the the "\\" ?

Comment: @nikhiljain Single slash is getting replaced. `\\\` is written to escape the single slash character. Please read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: @sadq i am asking abt the "\\" after the base folder pls see the question again

Comment: What do you mean by base folder. Your requirement is not clear